# How to disable Chart.js Radar Chart point labels

Tags: chart.js, radar-chart

I use Chart.js Version: 2.1.6 to create a radar chart, like this: [image: ChartoftheRadar]
I'm trying disable point labels (marked red on the picture).

I have tried several method, and for last set the labels font size to 0, but it didn't had effect.
Please help, if you can, here is my code:

```
var radarChartData = {
    labels: ["some labels"],
    datasets: [
        {% for data in datas %}
            {
                backgroundColor: "rgba({{ radarColors[loop.index0] }},0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba({{ radarColors[loop.index0] }},1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba({{ radarColors[loop.index0] }},1)",
                pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointDot: false,
                pointLabelFontSize : 0,
                scaleShowLabels : false,
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba({{ radarColors[loop.index0] }},1)",
                data: [some data]
            }   {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    ]
};

var options = {
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 2000,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    pointDot: false,
    pointLabelFontSize: 0,
    legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        display: false
    },
    pointLabel: {
        fontSize: 0
    },
    scale: {
        ticks: {
            display: false
        },
    }
};

var ctx = $('#radar-chart').get(0).getContext("2d");
var mychart = 
    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: radarChartData,
        options: options
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

options.tooltips.enabled = false

Is that what you're looking for?

[Common chart configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration)

Comment: Glad to help! Since you seem to be new here, may I point out stackowerflow's process of accepting an answer :)
http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer